# Error on Azure DevOps pipeline for Windows form application

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, msbuild-task

I am setting up build pipeline for Windows form application on azure devops with MSBuild arguments: `/target:publish /p:ApplicationVersion="$(Build.BuildNumber)"`. I am getting error below but the transformation files should not be included in the build so I am not able to find why publish is looking for this file.

> ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5327,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "bin\app.DEV.config" because it was not found.

Comment: Please, can you show structure of your project?

Comment: According to your description, it seems that app.dev.config does not use to build. You could check if you have referenced the `app.dev.config` in .csproj file. In addition to the file structure, you can share the content of your .csproj file with us.

Comment: app.dev.config is transformation file for app.config and yes the file in included in the project file

    <None Include="app.DEV.config">
      <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
      <DependentUpon>app.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
    </None>

Comment: Test with the same settings in project file, I notice that it will not copy the `app.dev.config` file. On the other hand, the transformation file shouldn't exist in the Bin folder.  Not sure why the build is looking for the file under the bin, you may check if you have set the path in the file. You also could try to use `Content` to replace `None`, then the app.dev.config file could be copied to publish folder.

Comment: Thank you for the help @KevinLu-MSFT

I am setting up clickonce deployment. I looked into further and tried from local and getting same error, also found that the file is being included in manifest file which should not be the case.

Comment: Thank you for your test. According to your description, the problem should be in the code itself rather than the azure pipeline settings. I think you need to check your source code and make sure it can run locally.Then you can move the build process to azure devops.

Comment: <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild> for dev transformation in csproj which was breaking the code with publish option.